Internal Server Error when verifying ID Token with Firebase Functions
I am trying to add a Firebase function that verify the id token given by a http request to verify user before letting him access my distant database.
I tried something using documentation in Node.js
Here is my code :
const { initializeApp } = require('firebase-admin/app');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountCred.json");

const app = initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

exports.verifyToken = onRequest((req, res) => {
    const { uid, token } = req.query;

    if (!uid || !token) {
        res.status(400).send('Paramètres manquants : uid et token sont requis.');
        return;
    }

    app.Auth().verifyIdToken(token).then((decodedToken) => {
        if (decodedToken.uid === uid) {
            res.status(200).send('Token valide.');
        } else {
            res.status(401).send('Token invalide.');
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    });
});


But, using this code, I keep getting this error :
Internal Server Error : 500

Here is my Flutter request code :
Future<void> validateTokenDB() async {
    String token="";

    try {
      token = await getIdToken() ?? "";
    } catch (e) {
      // Handle error
      print('Error getting token: $e');
    }

    String uid = firebaseAuth.currentUser!.uid;

    // Creating the query parameters
    Map<String, String> queryParams = {
      'uid': uid,
      'token': token,
    };

    // Constructing the URL with query parameters
    Uri url = Uri(
      scheme: 'https',
      host: 'link-to-the-function-url.a.run.app',
      queryParameters: queryParams,
    );

    try {
      // Sending the HTTP request
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);

      // Handling the response
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Request was successful
        print(response.body);
        print('Token updated successfully');
        return;
      } else {
        // Request failed
        print('${response.body} : ${response.statusCode}');
        Auth().signOut();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // Error occurred during HTTP request
      print('Error during HTTP request: $e');
      Auth().signOut();
    }
    Auth().signOut();
  }

Hope you can help me resolve this error.

Here is my code, it works for me hope it will for you juste change what you want with your needs like the path to the cred :
// The Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK to create Cloud Functions and triggers.
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/firebase-credentials.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

exports.verifyToken = onRequest( async (req, res) => {
    const { uid, token } = req.query;

    if (!uid || !token) {
        res.status(400).send('Paramètres manquants : uid et token sont requis.');
        return;
    }

    try {
        const authUser = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);
        if (authUser.uid !== uid) {
            res.status(403).send('Token invalide :' + authUser.uid + ' !== ' + uid);
            return;
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('Token valide.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(error.status).send(error.message);
    }
});

